# Bash variable within single and double quote

Tags: bash

Given I have the following `env` variables declared:

```bash
MY_VARIABLE_HERE=myValue
SECOND_VARIABLE=secondValue
```

How can I retrieve these variable within a single quote, wrapped in double quote. i.e. the following

```bash
echo '<tag><action name="$MY_VARIABLE_HERE" value="$SECOND_VARIABLE"/></tag>' > my_text.txt
```

So the expected output for the `my_text.txt`
would be

```bash
<tag>
  <action name="myValue" value="secondValue" />
</tag>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo '<tag><action name="'"${MY_VARIABLE_HERE}"'" value="'"${SECOND_VARIABLE}"'"/></tag>' > my_text.txt
```

Comment: This may cause weird output if expansions of variables contain glob characters.

Comment: Can you provide an example of such a case, please? @M.NejatAydin

Comment: `SECOND_VARIABLE='*'` will cause it to expand to a list of the files in the working directory after being substituted. Can fix by quoting, e.g. `value="'"${SECOND_VARIABLE}"'"` (and same for first variable)

Comment: I tried your example @tjm3772 and it works fine, without any problems. Output is: <tag><action name="myValue" value="*"/></tag>. I don't have a problem with your solution, but in my case it is unnecessary.

Comment: @Bianca Assume `MY_VARIABLE_HERE=' * '` and try it. And also with `MY_VARIABLE_HERE='hello  world'` (there are two spaces between `hello` and `world`): One of the spaces is lost in the output.

Comment: Yes @M.NejatAydin , these are indeed some particular cases, but I just solved the above problem. My solution above is not a general syntax that applies for everything. If you know how to deal with these problems, feel free to post your own solution, because I personally don't know how to do it.

Comment: @Bianca Just quote both variable expansions with double quotes and it will be solved. Filename expansion is not performed between quotes. Also, quotes preserve spaces as-is. You may consider reading this article:  [Quotes](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes)

Comment: Pretty sure glob expansion happens before variable expansion, so having globs in variables is no issue.

Comment: @xpusostomos Not true. Glob expansion (that is, filename expansion) happens _after_ variable expansion and, having globs in variables may have issues unless the expansion is quoted.

Answer (score 2):

Without any quoting magic you can use here-doc:

```bash
cat <<-EOF
<tag>
   <action name="$MY_VARIABLE_HERE" value="$SECOND_VARIABLE"/>
</tag>
EOF

<tag>
   <action name="myValue" value="secondValue"/>
</tag>
```

PS: If tab characters are used for indentation then `-` before `EOF` is required.

Comment: <<-EOF shouldn't actually be necessary, all that does is strip leading tabs. A heredoc can print whitespace without it.

Comment: Good point @tjm3772 I have now clarified it answer as well

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you can use the builtin command `printf`:

```
printf '<tag>\n  <action name="%s" value="%s" />\n</tag>\n' \
       "$MY_VARIABLE_HERE" "$SECOND_VARIABLE"
```